# Draw board with color blocks and numbers in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a `list` of `list` called `ListOfValues`. I want to draw a board according to the size of this list, and color some blocks black with white fill and the others with just black.  I tried and got the following:

[image: 2DBoard]

And my code:

```
import turtle

#sets screen characteristics
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')
wn.title('Chessboard')

#sets turtle characteristics
greg = turtle.Turtle()
greg.speed(0)

#draws and fills one square
def square(size,color):
    greg.color(color)
    greg.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        greg.fd(size)
        greg.lt(90)

    greg.end_fill()
    greg.fd(size)    

#draws the whole chessboard  
def chessboard(size):
    greg.pu()
    greg.goto(-(size*4),(size*4))
    LR = len(listOfValues);
    for i in range(LR):
        for j in range(LR):
            if(SomeValue == 1 ):
                square(size,'white')
            else:
                square(size,'black')
        greg.rt(90)
        greg.lt(90)
        greg.goto(-(size*(4)),(size*(4 - i - 1)))
chessboard(50)
```

I am missing two things:

- I need to place lines in each row and column so it looks like a board
- I need to put the number values from my array in the middle of each block

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Your code fails to define `listOfValues` so it's difficult to address your second question.  And `SomeValue` is also never defined.  Your code as posted does not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to place lines in each row and column so it looks like a board

This one is easy.  Instead of setting the color via `color()`, which sets both the *pen* and *fill* colors, instead use `fillcolor()` which only sets the *fill* color, leaving the *pen* color the default black.  You'll also need to put the pen down during the drawing but lift it up after each row, during its journey back to the left edge.

> I need to put the value from my array in the middle of the block

This question is trickier but basically you need to define `listOfValues` as a `list` of `list` of `int`, where each `int` is zero or one, or some such.  Then in your nested loop, do `SomeValue = listOfValues[i][j]` before testing its value.

If you want to write the number in the block, I'd allocate a separate *marker* turtle for writing the numbers.  And define an appropriate font.

Below is my rework of your code where I implement the above as well as attempt to center the board correctly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

listOfValues = [
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1],
    [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1]
]

def square(size, color):

    ''' draw and fill one square '''

    greg.fillcolor(color)
    greg.pendown()
    greg.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(4):
        greg.forward(size)
        greg.left(90)

    greg.end_fill()

    greg.penup()
    greg.forward(size)

def chessboard(size):

    ''' draw the whole chessboard '''

    side = len(listOfValues)

    greg.penup()
    greg.goto(-size * side/2, size * side/2)

    for i in range(side):
        for j in range(side):
            someValue = listOfValues[i][j]
            text, color = ('black', 'white') if someValue == 1 else ('white', 'black')
            square(size, color)

            marker.goto(greg.xcor() - size/2, greg.ycor() + size/2 - FONT_SIZE/2)
            marker.pencolor(text)
            marker.write(someValue, align='center', font=FONT)

        greg.goto(-size * side/2, size * side/2 - size * (i + 1))

# set screen characteristics
screen = Screen()
screen.title('Chessboard')
screen.bgcolor('lightblue')

# set turtle characteristics
greg = Turtle()
greg.hideturtle()

# set marker characteristics
marker = Turtle()
marker.penup()
marker.hideturtle()

screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience
chessboard(50)
screen.tracer(True)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome , Thank you.